# Android cancel toast on click

Tags: android, toast

I have a custom toast diplaying an image and some text. This toast is big enough to cover almost half of the screen. It has a duration of LENGTH_LONG because it contains much information.

In some cases this can be a bit annoying for the user. Is there any way to cancel the toast when the user clicks on it? If not, is there any way to cancel the toast when clicking anywhere outside the toast?

Thanks!

Comment: try to use AlertDialog it will give you the same functions that you need

Comment: Or PopupWindow for more design possibilities.

Comment: Use crouton library. Better than toast and with show and hide features on click

Comment: Make it as global, so you can use cancel() method from the toast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep a reference of you Toast, you can then use the `cancel()` method, documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29).

In order to know when you need to cancel the toast, you will need to intercept the touch event with the `OnTouchEvent` of your activity and get the position x/y of the touch event. Then you can compare it with `myToast.getView().getY()`and `getX()` to get the top left corner and `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on track. However, because the toast is displayed over a listview, and the listview items have onClick listeners, when a click over the toast is made, the touch event is consumed by the listview. How can I avoid this behavior? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to make a really clean and good looking code, I would create a custom ViewGroup (like a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) and override the `DispatchTouchEvent`. If you return false, the event will be stopped and won't go to the listview. Or you could just do nothing in the onItemClick method of the listview. In both case you need to know if a Toast is currently displayed. I never tested it but is seems that this should work : `toast.getView().isShown()`.

Comment: To avoid memory leaks, please consider keeping a `WeakReferece` to the toast so GC can clean it up if required.